# Не отменить закрытие окна с помощью e.Cancel = true;

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот такая проблема. Где мог ошибиться?

Да тут просто описывать нечего по сути, но вот

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true; 
}
```

Вызывается при закритие окна, должно препятствовать закрытию.

Comment: Подробнее пожалуйста. Хотя бы код покажите( ну и плюс опишите детальнее )

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А метод вообще срабатывает? Попробуйте подебажить чуток или поставьте MessageBox внутри этого метода...

Comment: Да, тут и была загвоздка. Внимание рассеялось. Спасибо большое:)